# Vertica Backup/Restore

Tags: vertica

I am Using Vertica 9.1.x and trying to setup Backup Policy. Vertica provides Utility vbr to Backup with Limitation of Same Number of Nodes and Same Node name.

Are there any other methods which can help in Backing up in such a way so that restore has no Limitation like above ?

Answer (score 0):

You can export individual tables and import them later if you need a different cluster size.
Or have a smaller cluster ready and use CONNECT to transfer the data between both.

Regarding the IP addresses you can try [this](http://www.bundesbrandschatzamt.de/~baron/blog/20170221-vertica-backup-and-restore.html) approach. Works for me. But in the end: It's your data and your risk.